# Sending steam gems in trade offer, using nodejs

Tags: node.js, bots, steam, steambot

i'm trying to make steam bot, which sends steam gems to my other account. for example: i have 500 gems and i want to send it one by one.

```
 function sendRandomItem() {
  manager.loadInventory(753, 2, true, (err, inventory) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const offer = manager.createOffer('partner_steam_id');
      const item = inventory[Math.floor(Math.random() * inventory.length - 1)];

      offer.addMyItem(item);
      offer.send((err, status) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(`Sent offer. Status: ${status}.`);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

How can i access steam gems? if i console.log(inventory) it's not even showing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  manager.getInventoryContents(753, 6, true, (ERR, INV) => {
    if (ERR) {
      console.log(`${ERR}`);
    } else {
      let My_gems = 0;
      const MyGems = INV.filter((gem) => gem.name == 'Gems');
      if (typeof MyGems[0] !== 'undefined') {
        const gem = MyGems[0];
        My_gems = gem.amount;
      }
```

I snippet of my bots code that finds gems.